# Loki chose wired network profile

Tags: release-loki, networking

I have multiple wired network profiles. How can i chose one in the loki gui? In Freya it was easily possible via the network panel, all profiles were listed and I simply clicked on it to activate. In Loki this is only possible with the wireless networks. Wired can only be switched on and off...

Comment: I have the same problem with the list of wired networks +1

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do this in the new UI. It's a very edge case where someone will be using 2 network connections on a regular basis. What you could do though is to create a shell script to ifdown and ifup the networks, then add a .desktop entry for it. At that point, you can just call your shell script to switch network adapter by selecting it from the applications menu.

Comment: After a year it seems this issue still persists.
I have the same problem.